# How to access php with port from another computer?

Tags: php, server, wamp

So I am using WAMP with the latest version and Im currently running a project with url `http://localhost:8080` since I am using `php -S localhost:8080` to run my app.

The computer's ip address is `192.168.1.4` and I access it through another computer by using `IPAddress/phpmyadmin` for testing. It works.

Now my problem is, how can I do that with a port? I tried 192.168.1.4:8080 but no luck.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You want to open like`192.168.1.4:8080/phpmyadmin` ???

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI I can access the database with 192.168.1.4/phpmyadmin but I am running an app using 192.168.1.4:8080 and I cant access it

Comment: check this https://john-dugan.com/access-wamp-from-lan-computers/

Answer (score 0):

First you need ip address then after colon you need to mention port number.

```
192.168.1.4:8000/WebDirectory
```

You need to replace "WebDirectory" with that directory name where you script is saved. 
If you script is in root directory then you don't need to "WebDirectory" or any other directory name. In this case you will use just ip address and port number after colon.

```
192.168.1.4:8000
```

Comment: I dont want to access the database. I am currently running an app with address localhost:8000

Comment: @FewFlyBy i have updated my answer. Please let me know, now can you access it ?

Comment: No dude haha i dont want to access phpmyadmin. I can access it directly with 192.168.1.4/phpmyadmin. My problem is that I have a website that runs with localhost:8000 and i dont know how to access it on another computer

Comment: @FewFlyBy PhpMyAdmin was just example. you have to replace PhpMyAdmin with that folder where you script is saved.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make a change in httpd.conf file.

#your root directory address in full

Directory "C:/WAMP/www"

Order allow, deny

Allow from all

Directory

After changing, you need to restart your WAMP server. then you can access from out side your own machine

Comment: You really should not run WAMPServer ( or any Apache installation ) from within `C:/Program Files/`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `php -S localhost:8080` to run your site then you are not using Apache to run the site you are using PHP's inbuilt dev server. You cannot use that remotely.

If you can access phpMyAdmin from another PC on your lan using `ipaddress/phpMyAdmin` then that is using Apache & PHP and doing so on Port 80.

Then assuming you have your site code in `wamp\www\folder` you should be able to run your site from another PC using the url `ipaddress/folder` and that will be using Apache and of course the default port 80

You should also read [The need for Virtual Hosts](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757) on the WAMPServer forum and create a Virtual Host for each of your sites/developments

Comment: Problem is that I am using a framework (makoframework) and if I put it in www the routes and asset files will not work properly

Answer (score 0):

To access the built-in php server from another computer, this is what worked for me:

1.- Navigate on the terminal to locate the folder of your php project. Let's say we have a folder named `myFolder` containing the file `home.php`

2.- Find your ipv4 ( `ipconfig` on Windows or  `ip addr` on ubuntu). Let's say you get: `192.168.9.8`

3.- Start the php buil-in server by using any port (for example 4000, 4800, 8000, etc. ): `php -S 192.168.9.8:4800`

4.- Now you can access your project by typing `http://192.168.9.8:4800/home.php` from other devices within your private network.

You can also read from the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Answer (score 0):

You can make the web server accessible on port 8080 to any interface with:

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8080
```

**Warning**

The built-in Web Server should not be used on a public network.

You can see [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) for more information